# How does PHP 7 remove the resources from the regular list?

Tags: php, php-extension, php-7, php-internals

I am upgrading a php extension to php 7, and I want to remove a resource that is been registered in the regular list using `zend_register_resource`and later I am closing the resource using `zend_list_close`. the closing function looks like this:

```
    PHP_FUNCTION(myFunc_cleanAndExit)
    {
     zval* rsrc = NULL;
     ...
     int res = zend_parse_parameters(ZEND_NUM_ARGS() , "r", &rsrc );
     if (res == FAILURE)
     {
        //handle it
     }
     ...
     zend_fetch_resource(Z_RES_P(rsrc), ./other args/..)
     ...
     zend_list_close(Z_RES_P(rsrc));
     ...
     }
```

originally in PHP 5, `rsrc` is removed using `zend_hash_index_del( &EG( regular_list ), Z_RESVAL_P( rsrc))`, so if this function is called twice, `zend_parse_parameter` returns `FAILURE`, because the resource is removed from the regular list and doesn't exist.

In PHP7, `zend_list_close` calls `zend_resource_dtor` (rsrc refcount is `2`(why is is incremented? after registering resource it was 1)) and cleans any memory that `rsrc` is holding up. But, the fun happens when we call it twice like this:

```
    myFunc_cleanAndExit($var-rsrc);
    myFunc_cleanAndExit($var-rsrc);
```

the second time zend_parse_parameter doesn't return FAILURE(cause the resource hasn't been removed from the regular list), and the refcount of the `rsrc` is incremented to `3` after parsing it, the type is -1 and ptr is NULL(assigned in zend_resource_dtor in the first call). When I call `get_resources()` in PHP script, I get the `rsrc` with its id and the type `UNKOWN`, which in PHP5 `rsrc` becomes `NULL`. Here are my questions:

1- when are the resources removed from regular list? (if I manually remove it from regular list using `zend_hash_index_del`, it breaks in the zend_alloc)

2- Is this Ok to have the resource active with type `UNKOWN` after closing it once? doesn't eat up the memory? If not, what should I do to have it as NULL?

3- When I register the resource, and check its refcount, it is 1, but when I call the closing function, after `zend_parse_parameter` the refcount gets incremented, why?

Thanks

sample PHP script:

```
    <?php
    $var_rsrc = myFunc_startUp();
    var_dump($var_rsrc); // resource(2) of type 'MyFunc'
    myFunc_cleanAndExit($var_rsrc);
    var_dump($var_rsrc); // resource(2) of type 'UNKOWN' (originally this was  NULL)
    myFunc_cleanAndExit($var_rsrc);
    var_dump($var_rsrc); // resource(2) of type 'UNKOWN'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is that the resource gets removed at request shutdown, specifically in `zend_hash_graceful_reverse_destroy`. You should also check the return value of `zend_fetch_resource` because it will return NULL (and emit a warning) for a destructed resource.

I think everything you're describing is normal, including `zend_parse_parameters` succeeding to parse a previously destructed resource. The program below exhibits the exact same behavior:

```
<?php
$r = popen('ls', 'r');
echo fgets($r);
pclose($r);
var_dump(get_resources());
pclose($r);
```

The refcount of your resource is 2 because the `SEND_VAR` opcode (i.e., passing a param to a function) will `ZVAL_COPY` it to the arglist, which increments the refcount. (It is later deref'd in `zend_vm_stack_free_args`.)

Regarding memory usage, I wouldn't worry about the resource eating up memory. We already know it doesn't leak as it gets cleaned up at `RSHUTDOWN`. And even if you were to manually remove the item from the hash, I don't think the underlying memory is guaranteed to be deallocated immediately.

Comment: Thanks @adsr, in PHP5 zend_parse_parameter returns FAILURE because the parameter actually doesn't exist and is removed from the list, why can't we have the same behavior in the PHP 7?

Comment: @Genjutsu Thanks for accepting my answer. I sort of doubt that this change was intentional. It's more likely a side effect of stack vs heap allocated zvals. As an edge case, you can argue that someone may want to reinstantiate their previously destructed resource, in which case zpp succeeding is desirable. Weighing that against back-compat with PHP 5, it's a toss-up.